# Custom access control in views

Tags: views, 8, users

I have Views page with list of enities. The URL is /admin/group/12/members

There is a route in *mymodule.routing.yml*:

```
  mymodule_members_list:
  path: '/admin/group/{id}/members'
  requirements:
    _custom_access: '\Drupal\mymodule\Controller\GroupController::access'
```

The Group entity has field contains group administrator email (field_admin_email)

What I need is to allow administrator to only access a view with group/{id} associated with his email.
(I have only problem with views access - it seems like views override my custom access method)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solved!**

Adding custom access to the Views is very easy: 
Just create own views access plugin by extending *Drupal\views\Plugin\views\access\AccessPluginBase* class.

Then implement custom access logic in *access* method and new rule should appear in **PAGE SETTINGS > Access** popup window.

Comment: For those who might find this helpful, I was returning TRUE on alterRouteDefinition() (from the custom AccessPluginBase plugin), access was still denied. I fixed the problem by checking some examples on the core and using: $route->setRequirement('_access', 'TRUE') ; on alterRouteDefinition().

Answer (score 0):

Use [Views custom permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_custom_permissions) module